# Какой GUI фреймворк выбрать для Desktop Java?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, gui, design

Имеется пример Desktop приложения[image: Пример]

Хотелось бы узнать у опытных Java-девов, какой фреймворк выбрать, чтобы реализовать GUI в таком стиле? Колеблюсь между Swing и JavaFX. Помимо красивого Flat Design запланировано задействовать плавную и красивую анимацию, как на gif.

Comment: Думаю, многие ответят JavaFX. Свинг более простой и устаревший вариант, насколько я знаю.

Comment: Вопросы опросники вроде как плохо задавать на SO, но по сабжу могу сказать, что я поддерживаю javaFX. Более красивый, более удобный, удобная стилизация через css.

Comment: На Swing такой дизайн сделать будет проблематично. Однозначно JavaFX

Answer (score 2):

В `java` есть **три варианта**, с помощью которых можно создавать приложения с графическим интерфейсом (я сейчас про компьютеры). **Я рассмотрю все варианты, и объясню, какие из них не подходят (и почему), а какой будет в самый раз.**

#### Вариант первый: [`java.awt`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Window_Toolkit)

[`AWT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/package-summary.html) расшифровывается как

> Abstract Window Toolkit (дословно - инструментарий абстрактного окна)

Этот пакет действительно **устарел**. `AWT` не очень подходит для одинаковой кроссплатформенной работы. К тому же у этой библиотеки возможностей просто меньше, чем у следующих двух, ведь эта библиотека гораздо более древняя, она появилась в самых первых версиях языка. А в "те времена" возможностей было куда меньше, чем сейчас, и о таком интерфейсе, как у вас в вопросе речи не шло.

На самом деле, **некоторые** классы из `AWT` используются до сех пор (менеджеры компоновки например).

**Вывод**:

> `java.awt` вам **не подойдёт**.

#### Вариант №2: [`javax.swing`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing)

Это уже упомянутый вам [пакет javax.swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html). `SWING` более гибок, в нём больше классов, а это значит, что он предоставляет больше возможностей. К тому же о кроссплатформенен и обеспечивает лучшее поведение компонентов, чем компоненты `AWT`.  Но `swing` тоже не совершенен. Да и сделать на нём *настолько красивый* интерфейс....

**Вывод:**

> `swing` конечно лучше, чем `AWT`, но сделать на нём *настолько красивый* интерфейс будет проблематично. К тому же, есть вариант ещё лучше (см. Вариант №3)

#### Вариант №3: [`javaFX`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX)

`javaFX` предоставляет гораздо более широкие возможности, чем `swing`.
В википедии сказано **даже так:**

> JavaFX — платформа на основе Java для создания приложений с **насыщенным** графическим интерфейсом

`javaFX` - на данный момент самая большая по количеству возможностей библиотека для создания десктоп-приложений на языке `java`. С помощью `javaFX` вы можете написать что-то вроде того, что вы показывали в вопросе. Не говорю, что это будет легко, но это хотя бы возможно.

Правда с версии `java11` `javaFX` поставляется отдельно от `JDK` (так как `java` в основном используется для разработки веб-сервисов на `spring framework`), но `javaFX` можно загрузить отдельно.

**Вывод:**

> `javaFX` - то, что вам нужно!